Wierd scaling factor while converting pixels to coordinates
I have a heatmap and the four corner coordinates. My task is to mark a new coordinate on the map. The map is not distorted. I am finding the distance of the new point from the left and bottom line is constructed from the top left, bottom left and, bottom right, and bottom left coordinates.
Further, I am finding the corresponding change in coordinates for each pixel.
corner_coords = [
    [-118.9883423, 34.8782616],  # top-left
    [-119.4855042, 34.2534752],  # bottom-left
    [-118.7960052, 33.7048225],  # bottom-right
    [-118.2988434, 34.3296089]   # top-right
]

n_rows, n_cols = size(normalized_band)
lon_min, lat_min = corner_coords[2][1], corner_coords[2][2]
lon_max, lat_max = corner_coords[3][1], corner_coords[1][2]

lon_per_pixel = abs((lon_max - lon_min) / n_cols)
lat_per_pixel = abs((lat_max - lat_min) / n_rows)

function point_to_line_distance(line_point1, line_point2, point)
    line_vec = line_point2 .- line_point1
    point_vec = point .- line_point1
    proj = (dot(point_vec, line_vec) / dot(line_vec, line_vec)) * line_vec
    perp_vec = point_vec .- proj
    return norm(perp_vec)
end

When I am plotting the corners on the map, I have to scale the points by a factor of 1.27 to accurately place it on the corner most pixel, like so:
new_coord = [-118.2988434, 34.3296089] #top right
dist_to_left_line = point_to_line_distance(corner_coords[1], corner_coords[2], new_coord)
dist_to_bottom_line = point_to_line_distance(corner_coords[2], corner_coords[3], new_coord)

pixel_x = round((dist_to_left_line / lon_per_pixel)/1.278) #wierd factor
pixel_y = round((dist_to_bottom_line / lat_per_pixel)/1.278) #wierd factor

Any idea why this might be happening?

It looks like your bottom left coordinate is wrong
